# Merging data sets in sas

Tags: sas

Suppose I have a dataset A:

```
ID Geogkey
1    A
1    B
1    C
2    W
2    R
2    S
```

and another dataset B:

```
ID Temp Date
1   95   1
1  100   2
1  105   3
2   10   1
```

How do I merge these two datasets so I get three records each for geogkeys with id=1 and one record each for geogkeys where id =2?

Comment: So you want 1/A/95/1  1/A/100/2 1/A/105/3 1/B/95/1 1/B/100/2 etc.?

Comment: @Joe Right thats correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want the cartesian join, you are best off doing that in SQL, if it's not too big:

```
proc sql;
create table C as
  select * from A,B
  where A.ID=B.ID
;
quit;
```

The select * will generate a warning that the ID variables are overwriting; if that's a concern, explicitly spell out your select (`select A.ID, A.Geogkey, B.Temp, B.date`).

Comment: Is there anyway to do this with a single merge statement? I know sql is less efficient than merge.

Comment: You are not necessarily correct. In this case SQL is likely as efficient if your data are not too numerous.  Merge cannot handle Cartesian join like this; you would need to use a keyed set statement which is more complex to program. I would use SQL unless you found it was unable to handle your data.

Comment: Not really.  You can do it in a data step, but you're looping over the rows to do it.  Stick with the `proc sql` solution.